# Can Cartthrob credits be used to reward customers?

Tags: cartthrob

I am planning a new site and the client would like to reward regular customers by giving the 'reward points' that can be redeemed at checkout.

Is this possible with credits? I am aware that DevDemon Credits can do this, just winging if CT can do it too.

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

It is but you'd need to buy the separate [Cartthrob Credits module](http://cartthrob.com/site/product_detail/credits) or use [DevDemon Credits](http://www.devdemon.com/credits/). Natively it's not supported unless you build your own module to handle that.

Comment: Thanks Ian. Yeah I was talking about the Credits module above for this. Have you used both? Just wondering if you have any pros or cons for either of them? DevDemon has a lot of other uses and I understand they are working in v.3 which will have a few enhancements. CT Credits doesn't mention much about offering rewards after purchase, more about micro-payments than anything else.

Comment: Yes, personally I'd recommend DevDemon Credits. It's the most feature rich credits module so you get more for your money and it's CT compatible. It's also more likely to see updates than the CT Credits module.

Comment: Ace, that was my gut feeling too. Many thanks Ian.